# java program arguments and VM argument

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm-arguments

I want to figure out how can I run a java program which demand different types parameters to be passed.
Here the instructions of the author's program :

RUN :

```
$ cd wmart/work/
$ java -jar WMartSimulator <seed> <maxDays> <daysForward> <membersFile> [<parameters>]
```

Java may require sufficient options depending on your environment. For example:

```
$ java -d64 -Xms1G -Xmx30G -Djava.library.path=/usr/ilog/cplex/bin/x86-64_debian4.0_4.1:/usr/local/lib -jar WMartSimulator.jar 0 30 7 member/type1.csv demandfile=demand/trial.csv\;demand/trial.csv:logdir=result/trial-type1
```

I've tried to execute the program by mapping his specific instructions to my owns. And here is what I've done :

In the program arguments of eclipse, I've put :

```
0 30 7 bin/work/member/type1.csv "demandfile=bin/work/demand/trial.csv"
```

And the VM arguments :

> -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files (x86)\LPSolve IDE\LpSolveIDE.exe"

After setting them up I got the following general description of my error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.iw.mace.environment.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:69)
    at edu.iw.mace.environment.Market.<init>(Market.java:94)
    at edu.iw.mace.environment.Market.<init>(Market.java:79)
    at org.wmart.core.WBoard.<init>(WBoard.java:67)
    at org.wmart.core.WAuctioneer.initialize(WAuctioneer.java:52)
    at org.wmart.core.WMart.setupAuctioneers(WMart.java:1339)
    at org.wmart.core.WMart.<init>(WMart.java:112)
    at org.wmart.core.WMartSimulator.<init>(WMartSimulator.java:83)
    at org.wmart.core.WMartSimulator.main(WMartSimulator.java:47)
```

The corresponding bloc codes of Settings.java:69 is :

```
public Settings() throws FactoryException, MaceException {

        try {
            config = new PropertiesConfiguration(PROPERTIES_FILE);
        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            log.error(e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
        config.setAutoSave(true);// line 69

        initProperties();
    }
```

I wonder if I have followed correctly what it is prescribed in the author's website :
https://github.com/ikfj/wmart/#run

Could you tell what is the wrong thing in my configuration ?. And also, if you can give me the specific documentation that deals with those specific problems.

Comment: What's the complete error message? as you can see yourself `edu.iw.mace.environment.Settings.(Settings.java:69)` really does not give any information about the actual problem.

Comment: The java.library.path property shouldn't point to a file, but to a directory (or a set of directories)